# GPS worked but stopped working

Tags: android, gps, android-location

I have created an app that would use GPS.
it was working properly but now its not even listening to location updates.
any idea of what happened to it?

Comment: post ur code to verify..

Comment: have u allowed mock locations on ur device?

Comment: yes, i have allowed it. also fine and course.

Comment: please, post more detail about your problem